# Notepad++ Find and Replace Multiple Lines in HTML file

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I've written a long post for to give a good amount of information about my problem. The bottomline is that I'd like to generate a specific layout in my 'find and replace' macro output so it can easily be coppied into Excel. I'm almost there but need some help to cover the last bump.

**Background**

I was looking to rent a house. For that, I wanted to know what price was usually asked per m2. I surfed to a big housing add website and manually coppied the price and m2 of each property into excell for to calculate the overal price/m2 so I would have an idea about prices in the different areas in the city.

While doing so, I wondered if I could automate this process to safe time. So I started surfing the internet because I've never done anything like this. I learned a lot in the meantime and by now, automating this task has cost me much more time than actually doing it manually ahaha, but I cannot give up now...! I'm so close!

**Source**

First of all, I take the source code of the housing add website. In the next extract you'll see some values:

- € 9.950 (this is the price/month)
- 528 m&#178- (this is the total m2 of the property, in this case 528)

  ```
  </div><div class="search-result-info search-result-info-price">
  <span class="search-result-price">€ 9.950 /mnd</span>
  <span class="search-result-info-small">Geen kosten huurder</span>
  </div>
  <div class="search-result-info">
  <ul class="search-result-kenmerken ">
  <li><span title="Woonoppervlakte">528 m&#178;</span>
  </li>
  <li>6 kamers</li>
  <li>In overleg</li>
  ```

**CURRENT PROCEDURE**

I copy the whole source code into Notepad++ and do two Find and Replace commands. First for the price, subsequently the surface (FYI: surface in Dutch is written as oppervlakte)

Find1

```
<span class="search-result-price">(.*?)/mnd</span>
```

Replace1

```
\r\nHITPRICE: $1
```

Find2

```
<span title="Woonoppervlakte">(.*?)m&#178;</span>
```

Replace2

```
\r\nHITOPPERVLAKTE: $1
```

Great! 
Now I do a search and mark command for the values HITPRICE and HITOPPERVLAKTE. Then hit Search > Bookmark > Remove all unmarked lines. The result is a nice list of all prices and surfaces which I can then copy to excell.

```
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 135
HITPRICE: € 9.950
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 528
HITPRICE: € 1.560
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 106
HITPRICE: € 1.250
```

However, the list shows price and surface on a different line each time. I can work with it, but I'd prefer the following format wherein both surface and price are combined:

```
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRICE: 106   € 1.250 
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRICE: 528   € 1.560 
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRICE: 135   € 9.950
```

Simply because, when copying into excel, this way the surfaces and prices will show side by side in different collumns straight away.

**PROCEDURE NUMBER 2**

So the following is what I've come up with so far; a single Find and Replace command:

Find

```
(<span title="Woonoppervlakte">(.*?) m&#178;</span>)|(<span class="search-result-price">(.*?)/mnd</span>)
```

Replace

```
(\r\nHITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS: $2\t$4)
```

This gives me the following result:

```
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS:    € 2.200 
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS: 135    
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS:    € 9.950 
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS: 528    
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS:    € 1.560 
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS: 106    
HITOPPERVLAKTEPRIJS:    € 1.250
```

So I'm almost there but the outpit separates the surfaces and prices on different lines. This is easily resolved in excel (just move all surfaces up one row) but I wonder if it is possible to tidy up this final aspect of my miniature automatisation process :-)

**THE QUESTION**

How to modify my 'find and replace' command for to create an output layout wherein both surface and price are combined on a single line, and seperated by a tab (so they result in different collumns once copied Excel)?

Answer (score 0):

Your input:

```
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 135
HITPRICE: € 9.950
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 528
HITPRICE: € 1.560
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 106
HITPRICE: € 1.250
```

Find/Replace:

- Find what: `\r\nHITPRICE`
- Replace with: `\tHITPRICE`
- Search mode: **extended**

Result:

```
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 135 HITPRICE: € 9.950
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 528 HITPRICE: € 1.560
HITOPPERVLAKTE: 106 HITPRICE: € 1.250
```

And if you want to separate numbers into their own columns,

- Find what: `:•`
  (`•` represents space here)
- Replace with: `\t`
- Search mode: **extended**

Then you can use **Text to Columns** in Excel **Data** menu to create numbers from these columns, so you can create calculations on them, e.g. €/m².